# Linking/assigning one EF class to other - virtual ICollection isn't present in migrations file

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a class called "Collection". It represents data that will be stored in Entity Framework database. Here is part of this class:

```
public class Collection {
   [...]
   [ForeignKey("PrimaryCollection")]
   public int? PrimaryCollectionID { get; set; }
   public virtual Collection PrimaryCollection { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Collection> CollectionsBasedOnThisOne { get; set; }
}
```

What I wanted to accomplish: my Collection can have "parents" or "children", so in "PrimaryCollection" is parent and "CollectionsBasedOnThisOne" are children.

I called "add-migration" function, but what Visual Studio generated is:

```
AddColumn("dbo.Collections", "PrimaryCollectionID", c => c.Int());
CreateIndex("dbo.Collections", "PrimaryCollectionID");
AddForeignKey("dbo.Collections", "PrimaryCollectionID", "dbo.Collections", "ID");
```

I think something's missing. **There is nothing about "virtual ICollection CollectionsBasedOnThisOne" in this migration. Why is that?**

PS:
I remember that when I create, for example, class called "People" that stores virtual ICollection of "Person" and "Person" has specified variable that stores parent ("People" class), Entity Framework create table like: "PeoplePerson". Shouldn't it create similar table for my case like, hmmm... "CollectionCollection"?

What is name for this kind of linking/assigning/connectiong data with each other in databases? What should I look for in google to learn about that?

Answer (score 2):

You only need an intermediary table for a many-to-many relationship.

For a one-to-many relationship like yours, all you need is a column specifying the ID of each child's single parent.

Comment: so how should it look like? Do I have to create somthing like array of int? What is "a column specifying the ID of each child's single parent"?

Comment: I mean the `PrimaryCollectionID` column. Learn about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key

Comment: So, what I have now will work without problems? Will "CollectionsBasedOnThisOne" work correctly?